# Not able to update task completely using Windows SharePoint Services Incoming E-Mail

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using Windows SharePoint Services Incoming E-Mail timer job to add email in a document library.On itemupdated event I am trying to update a workflow task.Its showing completed,however internally its not getting completed and rest of the flow is not working.Please suggest.

Comment: What does it mean “internally it's not getting completed”? Are there any error messages in SharePoint's log files? Do you have any logging in custom WF activities? Describe the problem in a bit more detail, and possibly provide source code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying.I have solved the problem.What exactly I was doing is using Windows SharePoint Services Incoming E-Mail timer job I was uploading .eml file in a document library.On Itemupdated event I was updating a task based on email body.However before task.update I had written base.DisableEventFiring() which was causing that error.
Now it is fixed . :)

xyz